# Bundle.main.url not finding my .obj file in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, 3d, metal

I am trying to load a .obj file into Xcode so I can load it using ModelIO.

I got a .obj file, along with a .model and .mtl file, from a website offering free 3D models. (unfortunately I can't remember the name, but I'm sure it's not important) I placed all 3 files into Assets.xcassets.

Then I use the following code to try and load the file. The OBJ file is specifically called "car.obj":

```swift
let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "car", withExtension: "obj")!
```

It should be returning a URL that I can use to create an MDLAsset with, but if I try to build the app it just shows the following error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value

Which implies that the file was not found, according the Apple's documentation. This leads me to believe I haven't imported the file properly, or I have a corrupt file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need placed to Assets.xcassets. Try placed into project folder. Just like on[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lv6S.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you edit your answer in a way that it answers the question without visiting external site, please?